# working with dates and times (struct tm) on arm embedded system using Zephyr RTOS

Tags: c, datetime, embedded

I am trying to get a current date time on my arm micro processor board and perform some simple math (change from GMT to EST, and convert to calendar time).

I have been able to get an accurate GMT time of the network via AT commands. It comes back in the following format: "20/01/02,16:31:07-20". I have parsed this char array and assign the pertinent values the the `tm struct`. I can print the individual values fine but the application just stops when I try to print with `strftime`. Once I get that working how would I convert this to calendar time (seconds from Epoch) I think `mktime` should do the trick but that fails as well I assume for the same reason. Anyone have any thoughts. Here is the code and output

```
    char datetime[] = "20/01/02,16:31:07-20";
    //just hardcoded for now to get formatting and math done properly
    char sep[] = " ,.-:/";
    char str[30];
    strcpy(str,datetime);
    struct tm *timekeeper;
    char* token = strtok (str, sep);
    int tempyear = atoi(token);
    if(tempyear < 100){
          timekeeper->tm_year = 2000 + tempyear;
          printk("year= %i\n",timekeeper->tm_year);
    }
    else{
          timekeeper->tm_year = tempyear;
    }
    token = strtok(NULL, sep);
    //months are set from 0 to 11 so -1 is needed to adjust
    timekeeper->tm_mon = atoi(token) - 1;
    printk("tm_mon= %i\n",timekeeper->tm_mon);
    token = strtok(NULL, sep);
    timekeeper->tm_mday = atoi(token);
    printk("tm_day= %i\n",timekeeper->tm_mday);
    token = strtok(NULL, sep);
    timekeeper->tm_hour = atoi(token);
    printk("tm_hour= %i\n",timekeeper->tm_hour);
    token = strtok(NULL, sep);
    timekeeper->tm_min = atoi(token);
    printk("tm_min= %i\n",timekeeper->tm_min);
    token = strtok(NULL, sep);
    timekeeper->tm_sec = atoi(token);
    timekeeper->tm_isdst = 0;
    printk("tm_sec= %i\n",timekeeper->tm_sec);
    char buffer[40];
    //strftime(buffer, 26, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", timekeeper);
    //int secondsfromepoch = mktime(timekeeper);
    strftime(buffer, 40, "%A", timekeeper);
    printk("test\n");
    printk("date and time= %s\n",buffer);
```

new code tried:

```
     timekeeper->tm_year = 120; 
     timekeeper->tm_mon = 1; 
     timekeeper->tm_mday = 1; 
     timekeeper->tm_hour = 10; 
     timekeeper->tm_min = 10; 
     timekeeper->tm_sec = 10; 
     timekeeper->tm_isdst = 0; 
     char buffer[40]; 
     printk("year= %i\n",timekeeper->tm_year); 
     printk("tm_mon= %i\n",timekeeper->tm_mon); 
     printk("tm_day= %i\n",timekeeper->tm_mday); 
     printk("tm_hour= %i\n",timekeeper->tm_hour); 
     printk("tm_min= %i\n",timekeeper->tm_min); 
     printk("tm_sec= %i\n",timekeeper->tm_sec);
```

output:

```
year= 2020
tm_mon= 0
tm_day= 2
tm_hour= 16
tm_min= 31
tm_sec= 7
```

new code tried output:

```
year= 120 
tm_mon= 1 
tm_day= 1 
tm_hour= 10 
tm_min= 10 
tm_sec= 10
```

Comment: Be aware that the [Zephyr C library](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/1.13.0/subsystems/c_library.html) is minimal and your build may be using a different C library.  If you use the `CONFIG_NEWLIB_LIBC` option it will use [Newlib](https://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html).  That is your question is dependent on the C library you are using rather then Zephyr RTOS specifically.

Answer (score 2):

The `year` field of `struct tm` expects a value of the `year - 1900`.

So in your case it should contain the value `120`, not `2020`.

Also, the pointer `timekeeper` is never set.  So when you attempt to dereference that uninitialized pointer via the `->` operator you invoked [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Change `timekeeper` to an instance of `struct tm` instead of a pointer:

```
struct tm timekeeper;
```

And adjust any instances of the `->` operator on it to `.`.

Comment: I gave this a trial but got the same results. I tried to manual input the data components and it still failed.

Comment: it runs fine and I can get the value manually from the tm struct but this line wont work strftime(buffer, 40, "%A", timekeeper);

Comment: timekeeper->tm_year = 120;
        timekeeper->tm_mon = 1;       
        timekeeper->tm_mday = 1;
        timekeeper->tm_hour = 10;
        timekeeper->tm_min = 10;
        timekeeper->tm_sec = 10;
        timekeeper->tm_isdst = 0;

        char buffer[40];

        printk("year= %i\n",timekeeper->tm_year);
        printk("tm_mon= %i\n",timekeeper->tm_mon);
        printk("tm_day= %i\n",timekeeper->tm_mday);
        printk("tm_hour= %i\n",timekeeper->tm_hour);
        printk("tm_min= %i\n",timekeeper->tm_min);
        printk("tm_sec= %i\n",timekeeper->tm_sec);

Comment: and here is the ouput

Comment: here is the out put
year= 120
tm_mon= 1
tm_day= 1
tm_hour= 10
tm_min= 10
tm_sec= 10

Comment: @AndrewRudd Add this to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The `struct tm` epoch year is 1900 not zero:

```
    if(tempyear < 100)
    {
          timekeeper->tm_year = 100 + tempyear;
    }
    else
    {
          timekeeper->tm_year = tempyear - 1900;
    }

    printk( "year= %i\n", timekeeper->tm_year + 1900 ) ;
```

or, because it is a simple conditional assignment you might prefer:

```
timekeeper->tm_year = (tempyear < 100) ? 100 + tempyear : 
                                         tempyear - 1900 ;
printk( "year= %i\n", timekeeper->tm_year + 1900 ) ;
```